# How to sum up a value without remove duplicated row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe:

```
   a     b     c     d    f
0  ai    Y     5     3    w
1  ai    Y     5     3    r
2  ai    Y     5     2    t
3  ai    Y     5     3    o
```

i wish my output is:

```
   a     b     c     d    f     e
0  ai    Y     5     3    w     5
1  ai    Y     5     3    r     5 
2  ai    Y     5     2    t     5
3  ai    Y     5     3    o     5
```

the column **e** is sum of the unique value in column **d**(mean the unique value is 2 and 3), anyone can share me the idea of the code?

this is my code:

```
 df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum the unique values.

```
In [280]: df['e'] = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].transform(lambda x: np.unique(x).sum())

In [281]: df
Out[281]:
    a  b  c  d  e
0  ai  Y  5  3  5
1  ai  Y  5  3  5
2  ai  Y  5  2  5
3  ai  Y  5  3  5
```

Comment: I notice this work but the calculation is wrong, does it affected when i have column a, column b, column c, column d, column f and the **column e **is based on **df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].transform(lambda x: np.unique(x).sum())** _while for my column f is a different value for all the row_

Comment: For the **x** from lambda x: np.unique(x).sum() is refer to the unique of **column d**, any idea on if i grouby then i fine the unique of the row and i apply the sum function?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the unique values from the Series then sum it.

```
df['e'] = df.d.unique().sum()
```

Comment: how about if groupby comment was used? because as follow the code provided it does not able to combined the .unique().sum()

Comment: John Galt has the answer. :D